# Split the ul list items into two columns with even and odd indexes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Here's the original:

`<ul>
<li>one</l1>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>`

and i'd like to turn it into:

`<ul>
<li>one</l1>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>two</li>
<li>four</li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
$("ul li:odd")​​​​​​​.appendTo($("<ul>").insertAfter("ul"));​​​
```

Another variant of the same solution:

```
$("<ul>").insertAfter("ul").append($("ul li:odd"));​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4FyAa/

Comment: thats excellent. could you please rewrite this code if the ul has a class name as "category"?

Comment: @user1499677 You should read the jQuery manual first, from which you will find out how to use class selectors (i.e. `ul.category`). Finally, you will get the suitable version: http://jsfiddle.net/4FyAa/1/.